# django-cms admin Page loads very slow when using CMS_PERMISSION

Tags: django, django-admin, profiling, django-cms

I have a site, where it takes between 18 and 25 seconds to load admin form for django-cms page (i.e. /admin/cms/page/127/) with CMS_PERMISSIONS = True. Without permissions the problem disappears.

Also this happens only when loading admin form, the page in frontend doesn't have such delay.

The site has more than 35k users - that might have something to do with the problem, however I'm not sure.

I use: Django 1.4 and django-cms 2.3.4

I tried to carry out some profiling but it's useless, it shows total time 127...500 ms when actually page loaded in ~20 s.

I also tried to use johnny-cache (with redis) to cache SQL queries but it also doesn't help.

Any ideas how to improve admin page load time in this case?

Comment: Same here ... I'd love to hear a solution if anyone has one.